# How to strip textfile using csv

Tags: csv, text, replace, text-files

Expecting to get downvoted and closed due to how embarrassingly basic the question is:

But what is the easiest way of going about finding and replacing (deleting) words in a text document (or text document equivalent) using a list of words delineated by commas? My options at the moment are a) manually searching and replacing each word or b) writing a c programme from scratch to do the job for me.

For instance the textfile including

```
apraxic
aprepitant
Apresazide
Apresoline
Apri
apricot
apridae
aprifoliaceae
...
```

(i.e. delineated by \n) and the csv including

> apple,apricot,april,...

End result of above would be

```
apraxic
aprepitant
Apresazide
Apresoline
Apri
apridae
aprifoliaceae
...
```

Comment: c) use a more suitable programming language. i.e. almost anything other then c

Comment: Show us a few lines of your file and your list and how it is supposed to look when we are finished. Then tell us what OS you use.

Comment: @MarkSetchell added some sample text. OS is whatever (Windows/Ubuntu/Debian/etc.). Equally, I'm not confined to any particular text-editor or ide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
fgrep -v -f <(tr ',' '\n' < verboten) textfile
```

where `verboten` is the name of the file with the list of forbidden words. The `<()` is *process substitution*, and it creates a pseudo-file with the result of what is inside the parentheses - in this case I translate all commas in your `verboten` file into newlines. The `-v` negates the search.

This is a `bash`-ism. If you use a different shell, you will need 2 steps:

```
tr ',' '\n' < verboten > verboten.col    # Make line into column
fgrep -v -f verboten.col textfile
```

Comment: Pleasure:-) Ensure you have no blank lines because they match everything.

Comment: Doesn't work in MinGW: sh: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: Ok, you will have to do it in 2 steps as it is a `bash`ism. Hold on a minute.